# Create a pencil effect style in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

I need to create a draw as you are drawing using a pencil and you fill it by using pencil. The effect should be like you are drawing using a pencil on fabriano paper or using ink, I need to fill the typefaces also in the same effect.

Like the images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effect > Stylize > Scribble

You can apply the effect to anything.

[image: Scribble]

Comment: When he reaches 25K rep we're going to circulate a petition to rename the board "Scott Stack Exchange." ;)

Comment: errrr.... I can shut up :)